# Combining Tornado and Flask templates

Tags: python, routes, flask, tornado

Is possible to combine Tornado and Flask web templates together?

For example: Use Index.html as "base" template setting up block for extensions:

Then ,extend index with "block" from Flask for Flask Routes
Then, extend index with "block" from Tornado for Tornado Routes..

Comment: What is your use case for it? May be it will be simpler to maintain symbolic links to base template.

Comment: @ Nikolay: ?, To build a website....

Answer (score 2):

Tornado templates uses syntax similar to Jinja, but the rendering engine is not Jinja. You might be able to get away with it, but then you would have to keep track of which templates are Jinja and which are Tornado.

For the sake of sanity, just keep them separate.

Answer (score 1):

You are not bound to the default template engine in Flask. Maybe you could somehow use Tornado's template engine in Flask, then it'd be possible to use the templates in both.